# I'd like to incorporate an advanced custom field into my Wordpress menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here's my code now:

```
$menu_icon = get_field('menu_icon');

if($menu_icon) {
    $m_icon = '<img src="'.the_field('menu_icon').'">';
} else {
    $m_icon = "";
};

$personal = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'personal',
    'menu'            => 'Personal Menu',
    'before'          => '$m_icon',
);

wp_nav_menu( $personal );
```

And here's what it spits out:

```
<ul id="menu-personal-menu" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item>
        $m_icon <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>$m_icon <a href="#1">SubLink 1</a></li>
            <li>$m_icon <a href="#2">SubLink 2</a></li>
            <li>$m_icon <a href="#3">SubLink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to have it produce something like this:

```
<ul id="menu-personal-menu" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><img src="path/sublinkimg1"> <a href="#1">SubLink 1</a></li>
            <li><img src="path/sublinkimg2"> <a href="#2">SubLink 2</a></li>
            <li><img src="path/sublinkimg3"> <a href="#3">SubLink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the general idea:
[image]

It's wrong for a few reasons. I know the advanced custom field: "menu_icon" probably isn't able to retrieve anything outside of a loop, and I'm not familiar enough with the wp_nav_menu() function to know whether or not it's possible to echo an image specific to the page it's displaying.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I notice right away is that you have extra single quotes, and php is translating the content [literally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php). You actually want the string contained in $m_icon, and NOT the string '$m_icon' which is not a variable.

```
$personal = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'personal',
    'menu'            => 'Personal Menu',
    'before'          => $m_icon, //this line was wrong, single quotes means 'literally this$ $tring'
);
```

Edit:
I took the liberty of writing a filter function for what you're trying to do. Cheers.

```
function insert_icons($items, $menu, $args){
    //check our menu name so we filter the right one
    if($menu->name=='Personal Menu'){
        //loop through the menu items
        foreach($items as $key => $item){
            //make sure object_id is set (this is the page or post id)
            if(isset($item->object_id) && !empty($item->object_id)){
                //grab the menu icon
                $menu_icon = get_field('menu_icon',$item->object_id);
                //make sure the previous line returned something
                if(isset($menu_icon) && !empty($menu_icon)){
                    //create our image string
                    $m_icon = '<img src="'.$menu_icon.'">';
                    //insert it into the page title
                    $item->title = $m_icon.$item->title;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items','insert_icons',NULL,3);
```

Comment: With quotes it outputs the string: <li>$m_icon<a href="#menuitem">menuitem</a>

Without: <li><a href="#menuitem">menuitem</a>

It's not pulling any data from the variable, though I couldn't say why... I think the solution lies with the $page_ID trick that Nishant suggested, but haven't had an opportunity to test it.

Comment: This seems to mean that the string contained in $m_icon is returning NULL. Try changing this: `if($menu_icon) {
    $m_icon = '<img src="'.the_field('menu_icon').'">';
} else {
    $m_icon = "";
};` to set something other than an empty string on the else condition. It would seem that get_field isn't returning what you're looking for.

I would definitely give the second parameter that Nishant suggested a try.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for and i don't have the correct solution for your entire problem right now but i can help you with getting custom fields to work outside the loops if that helps you :)

you just have to set the page ID after your field name for it to work outside of loop like this

`get_field('your-field', $page_ID);`

Comment: That's very helpful. I wonder if I could echo the page id into each menu item as part of this solution...

Comment: hmm actually that might be possible ... try it and please do share if it works for you :) it might be helpful for future..

Thanks